# Hash Join and Sort merger exception in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

**Cluster Infra:**

We have Flink standalone cluster with 4 nodes each with 16 cores of CPU and 32Gb of Physical memory out of which 16 GB is set to Flink Managed memory and rest all is set to UDFs and Java Heap.
Hence Per slot, we have assigned 1 core and 1GB of ram.

**Scenario Description:**

We are trying to join two Datasets, A and B where Dataset A is a tuple of **<String, ArrayList>** and Dataset B has a **custom POJO** and joining key for both the data set is **String**.

For both the dataset size is not guaranteed, at one point of time A can be large whereas at another point of time Dataset B can be larger. Also it is highly possible that one dataset can have the multiple list of duplicate entries to it.

**for example :**
Dataset A has information of <String, LocationClass> size = 51 mb 
Dataset B may have information of  size = 171 mb 
joining key: Location example, Mumbai, NewYork etc.

Hence to join this we have chosen a joinHint Strategy as **Repartition_Hash_First**. this strategy works fine sometimes and sometimes it throws the below exception,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Hash join exceeded maximum number of recursions, without reducing partitions enough to be memory resident.
Probable cause Too many duplicate keys.
```

So we have tried to go with Repartition_Hash_Second but the results are same.

Hence as per my understanding Flink internally creates a hash table for the side which provide viz, First or Second and another side of data gets iterated over to hash table and vice versa and since one of the key has lots of data which couldn't accommodate into actual memory of flink while createing a hashtable it is throwing an exception of **too many duplicate keys**.

So at second step we have tried to implement this with Repartition_Sort_merge and we got below exception,

```
java.lang.Exception:caused an error obtaining the sort input. the record exceeds maximum size of sort buffer.
```

Can anyone please suggest me if we need to increase the flink managed memory to 2 gb or even more than that ? or shall we opt some different strategy to handle this problem ?

Comment: First, some input on your question - it's very helpful to include what version of Flink you're using. Second, what kind of join are you doing (leftInner, rightOuter, etc)? Third, from one of the errors above, it sounds like you might have a really big record (e.g. the DataSet A ArrayList) - what's the max size of a record?

Comment: we are using Flink 1.0.18 and we want to perform left outer join. size of the record is not known but yes it must be a larger one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty clear to me that your problem is having a duplicate group that is too big.

Also, the duplicate group might be on both sides, yielding a O(n^2) size for that group, n being the max duplicate group size.

I'd advise that you deduplicate both sides beforehand if that's possible, using something like [DeduplicateKeepLastRowFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/api/java/org/apache/flink/table/runtime/operators/deduplicate/DeduplicateKeepLastRowFunction.html) for example. Or build finer keys with additional data from your rows.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.
can you share me an implementation example of this?

Comment: Also, will it work if I will increase the Flink managed memory for now?